# Отсутствие переводов на обновлённых страницах очередей проверок

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Посмотрел здесь, вроде такого вопроса не было еще и данная проблема еще не освещалась. На [странице проверок очереди закрытия вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/) такая ситуация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю имеет смысл добавить переводы или обсудить перевод данных строковых ресурсов.

### UPDATE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот еще нет переводов

### UPDATE

[image: модераторское]

> Администратор
>
> - Advanced stats
> - Audits
> - Review suspensions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15783
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15660
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15782
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15934
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15762
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15958
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15936
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15799
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15800
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15801
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15658
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15734
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15830
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15826
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15828
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15829
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15645
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15195
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15644
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15818
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15809
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15811
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15812
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15813
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15817
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15819
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15815
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15816
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15725
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15727
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15726
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15640
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15795
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15836
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15825
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15823
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15821
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15834
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15833
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15788
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15999
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15984
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15997
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15794
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15791

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая  rev 2021.2.23.38643

Comment: я отредактировал вопрос, или эти пропущенные строки вы тоже добавили?

Comment: я так смотрю там вообще с очередями сейчас не все гладко, могу скрины покидать,чтобы вы не искали :)

Comment: @Andrew добавлял пока только по очереди на закрытие (и некоторые смежные), как исходно было указано в дефекте. По всем очередям там больше будет, да. Но можно переформулировать вопрос, чтобы кучу разных не заводить.

Comment: Ещё немного модераторского)

Comment: @Qwertiy утвердил, применил